# JQuery Dialog box not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a div "passage-content" and when a button is clicked, this div's text is put into a jquery dialog box. 
Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="passage-section">
  <!-- Title -->
  <div id="passage-title"></div>

  <!-- The panel that will display the content -->
  <div id="passage-content">THIS IS A DIV</div>

  <!-- Button that when clicked activates a dialog box for the passage. -->
  <button id="max-passage" class="max"></button>
</div>
```

The text of "passage-content" is what I am trying to grab and insert into a dialog box.
I run into two problems.
1)   Nothing appears in the div on the page, but when I click my dialog box button the text only appears in the dialog box.
Here is the code

```
 //Opens a dialog box when the button max-passage is clicked
 $('#passage-content').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: 'Passage'
 });
 $('#max-passage').click(function() {
    $('#passage-content').dialog('open');
    return false;
 });
```

2) If I change my code a little bit, the text appears in the div, but then my JQuery dialog box button does not work.
Here is the code

```
//Opens a dialog box when the button max-passage is clicked
$('#passage').dialog({
   autoOpen: false,
   title: 'Passage'
});
$('#max-passage').click(function() {
  $('#passage').dialog('open');
  return false;
});
```

I think my problem is in the way I am calling #passage/passage-content, but I cannot figure it out.
Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: Is creating a [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/) possible?

Answer (score 0):

EDITED to reflect OP's desire to account for changes in data.

Once you change the div to a dialog, it won't be in the DOM the same way you expect anymore. So if you want a dialog with that content in addition to the original div, you can clone it.

Since you want the dialog to account for changes to the content in the div, you can wait to create the dialog box until it is needed, i.e., when the button is clicked, and then it will reflect the latest changes to the content.

I'm actually not 100% certain if you need the destroy stuff or not. I don't know the innards of jQuery well enough to know whether the previously created dialogs would clog up memory, or whether the usual garbage collection process would take care of those loose ends. I figured better safe than sorry, unless someone more expert than I am assures you that it isn't needed.

```
var $dialog;

$('#max-passage').click(function(){
  if ($dialog){
    $dialog.dialog('destroy');
  }

  $dialog = $('#passage-content').clone().dialog({
    autoOpen:true,
    title:'Passage'
  });
});
```

Here's a demo:
http://jsbin.com/mizoda/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Try storing passage-content dialog as a variable and then calling dialog("open").

Here's your code slightly modified:

[HTML]

```
<div id="passage-section">
    <!-- Title -->
    <div id="passage-title"></div>

    <!-- The panel that will display the content -->
    <div id="passage-content">THIS IS A DIV</div>

    <!-- Button that when clicked activates a dialog box for the passage. -->
    <button id="max-passage" class="max">Open Dialog</button>
</div>
```

[JavaScript]

```
//Opens a dialog box when the button max-passage is clicked
dialog = $('#passage-content').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: 'Passage'
});

$( "#max-passage" ).on( "click", function() {
    dialog.dialog( "open" );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aseeto/vyb00a85/

Comment: Are you making sure to load jQuery, jQueryUI, and jQuery UI CSS files before the javascript code?

It could be an issue with version numbers of these files as well. I saw some differences when I was fiddling with it. What versions are you using?

Comment: I am using v1.11.4.  Another thing is that the whole site is dynamic and the pass-content changes if the user goes to the page. So the page loads in the text for the pass content from a JSON file. I had it similar to @DLH's answer above but that keeps the same dialog in the window no matter if the passage-content updates itself

Comment: Sorry, I didn't catch the first time that you wanted to account for updates. See my new version to address this.